# how to mount volume in ElasticBeanstalk Docker container using only Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created the following simple Dockerrun file per the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) using a public container and it's successfully running a single instance.

```
 {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "sbeam/influxdb",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8086"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/data",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/data"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I want the `/data` directory to be mounted within the EC2 instance as a certain EBS volume. I've found answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957940/running-non-www-stuff-on-an-elastic-beanstalk-docker-container) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126850/mount-specific-ebs-volume-to-docker-under-aws-beanstalk)) that indicate a `.ebextensions` is needed, but since I am not uploading a .zip image for the container, how is this possible? Is it necessary to download the Docker container, add the `.ebextensions` directory, zip and re-upload?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood concerning the zip... Do you mean you don't provide the zip file and use `eb deploy` to deploy? If you have a `.ebextensions` folder in your repository it will push the content to your beanstalk environment with the rest.

Comment: I mean I am using Dockerrun.aws.json as detailed in the first link. Not using the command-line but the web UI. So that's all there is in the upload, just one file, no place to put a directory.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to follow option 3: "Create a .zip file containing your application files, any application file dependencies, the Dockerfile, and the Dockerrun.aws.json file." as explained in [your first link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html).

In your case the .zip file may only contain the Dockerrun.aws.json and the .ebextensions folder.

In order to attach the EBS volume to your instance, you can check this article: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx224DU59IG3OR9/Customize-Ephemeral-and-EBS-Volumes-in-Elastic-Beanstalk-Environments. It will give you indications concerning the content of the .config file that will be inside the .ebextensions folder